# How to set up a smart card for web login?

Tags: php, smartcard

I'm a web developer with a login system (in PHP) that I would like to extend to allow those with a smart card to sign into the system.  But I have no idea where to begin and I don't have a massive budget to just throw at this.  I'd like to keep the cost under $50.  Here are a few areas I've researched but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

1)  I need a smart card.  No one seems to sell single smart cards at affordable shipping rates (I'm only finding $2 to $5 for a single card and then $40+ for shipping).  Then again, I'm not entirely sure which of the 200 varieties of smart card out there is the correct solution for my application.  What sort of smart card should I even be looking at?

2)  How to write data to the smart card?  I'm only finding card readers out there (Newegg).  Do card readers write data as well or is there specialized writer hardware?

3)  What steps are necessary to get the data onto the smart card?  I'm envisioning data from my PHP application that needs to be written to the smart card and then somehow it gets written then later that data somehow gets sent back to the PHP application.  Maybe this isn't how smart cards work, but then again I've never held one in my hands.  I'm familiar with 3-track magnetic stripe readers and writers but not smart cards.

4)  How to set up the web browser to use the smart card?  I found some instructions for Firefox on Windows, but what about other browsers and OSes?  I feel like once I've got the actual hardware in my hands, this may or may not be obvious but it seems like it should be clearly spelled out somewhere yet it isn't.

5)  How to get PHP to recognize and authenticate the user?

Comment: I've never used a card for this so can't provide a full answer but: 1) Maybe a Java Card? Pretty cheap and relatively easy to get up and running quickly. 2) Google ACS card reader, they're a good brand. 3) Smart card authentication could work where the server provides a card with a random nonce that it signs using a secret key that the card and server both know, send the signed nonce back and have the server check it. P.S. These are for a DYI solution but as with most security things it's better to use a tried and tested system rather than implementing your own.

Comment: Why a smart card? Why not Google Authenticator, for instance?

Comment: Windows support?

Comment: I went through a similar dilemma at my company not too long ago where they wanted two factor auth but didn't want to add to the budget so we used google authenticator. It provides them with two factor auth and since they all have smart phones that the company already pays for and they don't need an extra piece of equipment to lose :)

Comment: After doing some more research into Google Authenticator, the reason the recommendation was confusing was because it looked like it was only for mobile devices and somehow related only to Google accounts. I think I finally understand how it works and any sign in system could be used with it because it is based on a publicly available IETF RFC.  I just need to generate my own secrets and follow the relevant RFC to generate the expiring number on the web server to compare the user's temporary token with.

Comment: I got Google Authenticator compatible code working on a test basis.  Looks pretty solid and much more flexible and affordable than smart cards.  Thanks schroeder and @psudeo-reality.  You saved me both a headache and money.  Granted you guys didn't technically answer the original question so it would be improper to issue the green checkmark (SE policies = meh), but hopefully these comments will guide others onto a similar path away from smartcard insanity toward the more rational and sane RFC 6238 and its pre-built implementation in Google Authenticator.